# expressjs: how to use authentication function in another file attached to server.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, authentication

Imagine that I have the following piece of code in server.js

```
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user_id) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + 'login.html');
});
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.userID === 'a' && req.body.password === 'b') {
        req.session.user_id = req.body.userID;
        res.redirect('main');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
app.get('/main', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/main.html');
});
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    delete req.session.user_id;
    res.redirect('/');
});

require('./latestNews.js')(app);
require('./featuredNews.js')(app);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/404.html');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("listening on " + port);
});
```

The user will first see the login page. Once he has logged in he can see the main page. Function **checkAuth** is used in app.get('/main',... in order to achieve this.

I attached two other files latestNews.js and featuredNews.js. Those includes also app.get, app.post, ... functions and looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("/latestNews", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/latestNews.html');
    });
}
```

Those are thus exported as modules and added to server.js as follows:

```
require('./latestNews.js')(app);
require('./featuredNews.js')(app);
```

I made a server.js, latestNews.js and featuredNews.js in order to separate the work and keep the code short instead of one long file.

**My problem is now as follows:**

How can I pass the 'checkAuth' function to the latestNews.js and featuredNews.js So I can use it like this ?

```
app.get("/latestNews", checkAuth (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/latestNews.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Router that has this check and is mounted to your app :

```
authorizedRouter = express.Router();

authorizedRouter.use( checkAuth );

app.use( '/', authorizedRouter );

require('./latestNews.js')(authorizedRouter);
require('./featuredNews.js')(authorizedRouter);
```

Just be careful where you mount your router. If you want to mount it at the `/` of your app, you should put it after all of your `app.get/app.post` declarations.

Comment: Just one extra question. Thus I use 'authorizedRouter' instead of checkAuth on my app.get/app.post declarations ?

Comment: Think of the Router as a sub app. You can do `authorizedRouter.get/.post(..)`. Sometimes it might be better to use the checkAuth, based on your routes declaration. Router will capture all routes that have not been captured so far.

Comment: Aaaah now I get it ! Thanks a lot ! :)